# Have checkbox in addition to "Select All" redundant?

Tags: checkboxes, multi-selection, winforms

Is having an additional checkbox to select all redundent and add unneeded complexity?  The user frequently (maybe 40% of the time) selects numbers 1-33 as option so I would like to add a checkbox that selects those numbers.  However it is not hard to select all then uncheck L and 34-62.  So I don't know if I'm wasting time here making it worse.  The user would be educated on what the new T box does so that is not a problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a question for your users. I encourage A/B testing, one with the 1-33 checkbox, one without.

But if I were you, I think the 40% data is enough to convince stakeholders that a 1-33 checkbox would be helpful.

Comment: Nothing that formal honestly I can do whatever I want just making something for internal department use.

Comment: Well, UX isn't UX without data. Ask your users even if they're internal.